# If statement not triggering when trying to match strings

Tags: string, python-3.x, if-statement, string-matching, boolean-logic

I'm attempting to pick out strings containing a specific character (*) in an if/else statement using Python's `in` command. It works in the terminal, but the if statement isn't picking up on it for some reason.

In the terminal:

`match = '*moustache'`

`'*' in match
Out[27]: True`

But when I try to use it in an `if` statement,

`if '*' in match == True:
    print(match)`

does absolutely nothing. Why? Is there a different/better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you remove the == True.

```
if '*' in match:
    print(match)
```

The if statement will evaluate to True and then the print line will execute.

Comment: I literally just figured this out on my own, I feel silly. Thank you!